# display image from SD card or internal storage to view pager android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

have an activity which reads images from drawable folder and shows them in viewpager like slide show. below is my code for that. Now I want to show images from my SD card or internal storage in to viewpager. what changes should be made in below code to read images from SD card or internal storage and display them in viewpager like slide show.

**Activity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 3000,3000);

    }
    public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                    } else {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }

                    }


                ;

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
   private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.index1,R.drawable.index2,R.drawable.index3,R.drawable.index4,R.drawable.index5};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return images.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return view == object;
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);


        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);

    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237382/5402482

Comment: too complicated , Im confused

Comment: @emin, you first need to basically have a function to load images as bitmaps. After that you can put them wherever you want.

Comment: @AndreiT , Could u help me about that ,

Comment: @KavachChandra answer is good too, the difference between his answer and my answer is that I use Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Picasso to load images from sdcard. Guide here: 
[Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

In your case:

```
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); // retrieve the storage dir
    Picasso.with(context).load(new File(baseDir + File.separator + your_filename)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: which part of my code should I add this code, adapter page ?

Comment: Based on you code, I would basically have a list of strings with the names aded and every time when I load an image I add it to the path for Picasso(your_filename). But you can do it as you please.

Comment: I have image file ( file name is image ) in my Sd card and images name are  index1.png ,index2.png ,.. until index5.png ,Could you improve my code about that, please

Comment: I think this is a thing you must try. Here we do not code for you, but rather instead help you find the answer.

Comment: I can sellect images from gallery ( internal stroge ) but I could not to display on screen like slide show , Could you help me about that.